# Django redirect to latest created article

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect people to the latest article they created just after submitting.

The url doesn't use id but slugs how can I do it? I was thinking to something like this :

**views.py**

```
def article_id(request, slug):
    context = {'article_id': get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)}
    return render(request, 'article_id.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='/user')
def article_ajouter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save()
            save_it.user = request.user
            save_it.save()
            object = Article.objects.get(article_id)
            redirect(object, permanent=True) #I don't know if I am completely mistaken.
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'article_ajouter.html', context)
```

Any suggestions in order to do this redirection?

---- UPDATE ----

**article/urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', views.article_id, name="article_detail"),
```

**article/views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
    save_it = form.save()
    save_it.user = request.user
    save_it.save()
    return redirect('article_detail', article_id=save_it.slug)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a local variable called `article_id` defined, so this code would fail because it would try and pass the view with that name to `Article.objects.get()`, which would make no sense at all.

However there is no need to do any query; `save_it` is already the article you want. If the Article class has defined a `get_absolute_url` then this code would work (with one change, see below); if not then you would need to use the URL pattern name in your redirect call.

The final change is that you need to actually *return* the redirect, just like you return any other kind of response.

So, assuming you've defined a URL for your article_id view that looks like this:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', article_id, name='article_detail'),
```

then you would do this:

```
return redirect('article_detail', slug=save_it.slug)
```

(I'd also point out that "article_id" is a strange name for a view; it probably wants to be called "article_detail" anyway.)

Comment: I tried, but I am encoutering this error message `Reverse for 'article_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'article_id': 'test-article-two'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+)/$']` why is that ? I added an update to my post to see how I did it.

Comment: found it, worked well like this `return redirect('http://.../article/' + str(save_it.slug))` but was wondering if there is a way where I shouldn't add the url because I don't want to change all urls if I change my domain name.

Comment: Sorry, replace article_id with slug there, I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def article_id(request, slug):
    article_id = Article.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)
    context = {'article_id': article_id}
    return render(request, 'article_id.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='/user')
def article_ajouter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.user = request.user
            save_it.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article_detail', args=(save_it.slug,)))
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'article_ajouter.html', context)
```

This will be your url

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.article_id, name='article_detail'),
```

This should get it working if any other error. please do notify